# what is a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'length_$rn$' on line 4 error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing a problem that I know I got correct. the question is

Write code using find() and string slicing (see section 6.10) to extract the number at the end of the line below. Convert the extracted value to a floating point number and print it out.

the main text is `text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475"`

I wrote

```
text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475";
text2=text.find('0.8475')
print(text [text2:text.length])
```

my output is supposed to be
`0.8475`
I want to know what Im doing wrong

Comment: Strings in Python do not have the attribute `.length`. You want `text[text2:]`.

Comment: If you want to get the length of something use len(myvar).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
    >>> text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475"
    >>> text2 = text.find('0.8475')
    >>> print(text[text2:len(text)])

output: 0.8475
```

All I did was change the 'text.length' to len(text) like so:

```
print(text[text2:len(text)])
```

Instead of:

```
...
...
print(text [text2:text.length])
```